# How to append pandas dataframes with different shapes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to append two pandas DataFrames that are of different shape. Here are sample DataFrames for reproducibility:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4],
                    'val': ['x','y','w','z'],
                    'val1': ['x1','y1','w1','z1']
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [5,6,7,8],
                    'val2': ['x1','y1','w1','z1'],
                    'val': ['t','s','v','l'],
                   })
```

I'd like to append `df2` to `df1`. Expected behavior: Non-matching columns, in this case `val2` would just be dropped. Retain column ordering of `df1` and reset index in appended DataFrame.

```
   id  val val1
0   1   x   x1
1   2   y   y1
2   3   w   w1
3   4   z   v1
4   5   t   NaN
5   6   s   NaN
6   7   v   NaN
7   8   l   NaN
```

To clarify, not looking for inner join. Need all the columns from `df1` and additionally, also print the columns that didn't intersect between the dataframes.

Comment: Do you want `val1` to be dropped too?

Comment: Could you add your expected output in the question?

Comment: Updated the question with expected output.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please tell me if it is your desired outputs

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) With [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) (**Edited to match your excepted outout**):

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).reindex(df1.columns, axis='columns')
```

output:

```
   id  val val1
0   1   x   x1
1   2   y   y1
2   3   w   w1
3   4   z   z1
4   5   t   NaN
5   6   s   NaN
6   7   v   NaN
7   8   l   NaN
```

For columns that didn't intersect, you can either use:

```
df1.columns.symmetric_difference(df2.columns).tolist()
```

To get the columns that didn't intersect **fully** or at all, output:

```
['val1', 'val2']
```

**OR:**

```
df2.columns.difference(df1.columns).tolist()
```

To get the columns that didn't intersect **at all**, output:

```
['val2']
```

Comment: It seems that OP also wants to  "print the columns that didn't intersect between the dataframes". You can add the following line to your answer to accomplish that: `df2.columns.symmetric_difference(df1.columns).tolist()`.

Comment: @HarryPlotter Not reading edits until the end is a bad habit of mine, thank you, will edit.

Comment: @HarryPlotter Your solution returns both `val2` and `val1` but `val1` did intersect partially, so I will add another piece of code solely for `val2` and other `df2` non-matching columns.

Comment: Yeah, the description is not clear enough to understand which case OP wants. Looks good that way.